# Terraform Import aws security group resources created using terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws//modules/web

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have created a aws security group using the terraform provided aws module which is terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws//modules/web. Below is the snippet of code used. Resource created properly

```
module "app_security_group" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws//modules/web"
  version = "3.17.0"

  name        = "web-server-sg"
  description = "Security group for web-servers with HTTP ports open within VPC"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress_cidr_blocks = module.vpc.public_subnets_cidr_blocks
}
```

But not able to import using below command

```
terraform import -var aws_region=us-east-1 -state-out=us-east-1-recover.terraform.tfstate module.app_security_group.aws_security_group.web-server-sg sg-01c3b636f23c07ed0
```

getting error

```
Error: resource address "module.app_security_group.aws_security_group.this" does not exist in the configuration.

Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in module.app_security_group. For example:

resource "aws_security_group" "web-server-sg" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

Comment: Please describe the situation more. You say that the resource was created successfully by your terraform code, so why are you trying to import it?

Comment: What does the code inside the module look like? Is the module part of your codebase, or imported through another process?

Comment: `terraform import` is used to import infrastructure you created manually or using another configuration outside of your current Terraform config. Since you've already successfully created the security group using the module block, it exists in your state file and there is no need to import it. You can read more here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this command**

> terraform import -var aws_region=us-east-1 -state-out=us-east-1-recover.terraform.tfstate `module.app_security_group.web-server-sg` sg-01c3b636f23c07ed0

**Also note that when you created the resource then it should have already added to the statefile**